# NiFi Access Policy Provider error using AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, apache-nifi

So I got past my AzureAD App setup and configured and have NiFi setup to look at the AzureAD App but now I have an issue with the Access Policy Provider.  I am also using AzureAD App Roles vs AzureAD Group.  Any help would be wonderful as it seems getting NiFi setup for AzureAD is overly complicated but i need it setup for that.

> ERROR [main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'niFiWebApiConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.PrePostMethodSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.nifi.web.security.configuration.AuthenticationSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: Unable to locate configured Access Policy Provider: azure-graph-user-group-provider

Here is my configuration section of the authorizers.xml

```
    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>azure-graph-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.azure.AzureGraphUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Refresh Delay">5 mins</property>
        <property name="Authority Endpoint">REDACTED</property>
        <property name="Directory ID">REDACTED</property>
        <property name="Application ID">REDACTED</property>
        <property name="Client Secret">REDACTED</property>
        <property name="Group Filter List Inclusion">REDACTED</property>
        <property name="Page Size">100</property>
        <property name="Claim for Username">email</property>
    </userGroupProvider>

    <accessPolicyProvider>
        <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider">azure-graph-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity"></property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
        <property name="Node Group"></property>
    </accessPolicyProvider>

    <authorizer>
        <identifier>managed-authorizer</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.StandardManagedAuthorizer</class>
        <property name="Access Policy Provider">azure-graph-user-group-provider</property>
    </authorizer>
```

Here is my nifi.properties file:

```
# OpenId Connect SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.oidc.discovery.url=REDACTED
nifi.security.user.oidc.connect.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.read.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id=REDACTED
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.secret=REDACTED
nifi.security.user.oidc.preferred.jwsalgorithm=RS256
nifi.security.user.oidc.additional.scopes=User.Read,openid,profile
nifi.security.user.oidc.claim.identifying.user=email
nifi.security.user.oidc.fallback.claims.identifying.user=upn
nifi.security.user.oidc.claim.groups=roles
nifi.security.user.oidc.truststore.strategy=JDK
nifi.security.user.oidc.token.refresh.window=60 secs
```